# Fireworks shortcut keys for expand/contract selection

Tags: html, css, photoshop, fireworks

What's the keyboard shortcut in Fireworks for expanding or contracting a selection size?

I often use the Slice tool with images, but sometimes I don't get the selection perfect, and want to increase or decrease its area by 1 pixel.

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties Inspector at the bottom of Fireworks on the left hand side there it shows the current width and height of an object and it allows you to adjust those values.

Comment: @UmairFarooq I don't think that's good advice.  If the OP was able to find the question, someone else might also, and an answered question is always better than an unanswered one.